# Django, view email fetched by imaplib on my webpage

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, email

I'm trying to create a mail client using Django.

I am fetching the body of the emails from my inbox this way using imaplib:

```
def get_email_body(username, password, imap, email_id):
   USERNAME = username
   PASSWORD = password
   IMAP = imap

   mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP)
   mail.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

   try:
       mail.select("inbox")
       result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")

       ids = data[0]
       id_list = ids.split()
       current_email_id = int(id_list[-1]) - int(email_id)
       result, data = mail.fetch(str(current_email_id), "(RFC822)")
       raw_email = data[0][1].decode("utf-8")
       return raw_email
   except Exception as ex:
       print(ex)
```

How can i display my emails from this form:
[multipart email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmv0o.png)
to this form:
[beautiful gmail email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjbb8.png)

I would be thankful if you give me at least directions to study the problem.
Thank you!

Comment: You need to parse the message first. Check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html